# Who is Kalakanja?

Tags: asuras

Today I learn something about a monster Kalakanja . All I know right now is that he is the son of sage Kashyapa and Kalaka. I try to search some more information about his life time and achievement that he gain in his life time but not find anything. Can anyone give me some information on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kalakanja is not a single Danava but they are group of Danavas and are are known as Kalakanjas. They were the sons of Sage Kashyapa and Kalaka as described in [Vishnu Purana, Book 1, Chapter 21](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp056.htm).

> Vaiswánara had two daughters, Pulomá and Káliká, who were both married to Kaśyapa, and bore him sixty thousand distinguished Dánavas, called Paulomas and Kálakanjas, who were powerful, ferocious, and cruel.

Please note that, in footnotes of the same chapter, it is given that:

> The word is also read Kúlakas and Kálakeyas: the Mahábhárata, I. 643, has Kálakanjas.

This is also identified in [Shrimada Bhagavatam, 6.6.33-36](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/6/33-36).

> vaiśvānara-sutā yāś ca
>   catasraś cāru-darśanāḥ
>   upadānavī hayaśirā
>   pulomā kālakā tathā
>   upadānavīṁ hiraṇyākṣaḥ
>   kratur hayaśirāṁ nṛpa
>   pulomāṁ kālakāṁ ca dve
>   vaiśvānara-sute tu kaḥ
>   upayeme ’tha bhagavān
>   kaśyapo brahma-coditaḥ
>   paulomāḥ kālakeyāś ca
>   dānavā yuddha-śālinaḥ
>   tayoḥ ṣaṣṭi-sahasrāṇi
>   yajña-ghnāṁs te pituḥ pitā
>   jaghāna svar-gato rājann
>   eka indra-priyaṅkaraḥ
>
> Vaiśvānara, the son of Danu, had four beautiful daughters, named Upadānavī, Hayaśirā, Pulomā and Kālakā. Hiraṇyākṣa married Upadānavī, and Kratu married Hayaśirā. Thereafter, at the request of Lord Brahmā, **Prajāpati Kaśyapa married Pulomā and Kālakā, the other two daughters of Vaiśvānara. From the wombs of these two wives of Kaśyapa came sixty thousand sons, headed by Nivātakavaca, who are known as the Paulomas and the Kālakeyas**. They were physically very strong and expert in fighting, and their aim was to disturb the sacrifices performed by the great sages. My dear King, when your grandfather Arjuna went to the heavenly planets, he alone killed all these demons, and thus King Indra became extremely affectionate toward him.

Paulamas and Kalakanjas were defeated by Arjuna when he was on the way to Svargaloka. It is described in [Mahabharata, Vana Parva, SECTION CLXXII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03172.htm). The name of the city where they were living was known as Hiranyapura, that was created by lord Brahma himself.

> Once on a time a Daitya's daughter, named Pulama and a mighty female of the Asura order, Kalaka by name, practised severe austerities for a thousand celestial years. And at the end of their austerities, the self-create conferred on them boons. And, O king of kings, they received these boons,--that their offspring might never suffer misfortune; that they might be incapable of being destroyed even by the gods, the Rakshasas and the Pannagas; and that they might obtain a highly effulgent and surpassingly fair aerial city, furnished with all manner of gems and invincible even by the celestials, the Maharshis, the Yakshas, the Gandharvas, the Pannagas, the Asuras and the Rakshasas. O best of the Bharatas, this is that unearthly aerial city devoid of the celestials, which is moving about, having been created for the Kalakeyas, by Brahma himself. And this city is furnished with all desirable objects, and is unknown of grief or disease. And, O hero, celebrated under the name of Hiranyapura, this mighty city is inhabited by the Paulamas and the Kalakanjas; and it is also guarded by those mighty Asuras. And, O king, unslayed by any of the gods, there they dwell cheerfully, free from anxiety and having all their desires gratified, O foremost of kings. Formerly, Brahma had destined destruction at the hands of mortals. Do thou, O Partha, in fight, compass with that weapon--the thunder-bolt--the destruction of the mighty and irrepressible Kalakanjas.'

Comment: Nice find yet again. So that's how i guessed that you have a lot Puranas with u in book forms.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks, your comments are always a motivation for me. :-)

Comment: haha ..that's a bit too much.. but thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is very good information on Kalakanja.